# Meaning of $[A,B]$ when $A$, $B$ are self-adjoint

Tags: matrices, lie-algebras, notation, hermitian

This is just a question about notation, but it got no useful answers on math.stackexchange.

Let $L$ be the Lie algebra of $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices, with Lie bracket $(A,B)\mapsto i(AB-BA)$.

In a context where $A$ and $B$ are understood to be elements of $L$, I'd like to write $[A,B]$ for the commutator of $A$ and $B$, but I'd also like to write $[A,B]$ for the Lie bracket of $A$ and $B$.  Obviously, because the commutator and the Lie bracket are not equal, I can't do both.

Is there a well-established standard about what the symbol $[A,B]$ means in this context?

(Note:  Dirac, in his papers on quantum mechanics, uses $[A,B]$ to mean the Lie bracket, not the commutator.  But I don't want to assume that the notation used by physicists in the 1930s is standard among mathematicians in the 21st century.)

Comment: This is one of the common confusions caused by the physicists' habit of treating the space *Hermitian* matrices as a Lie algebra rather than the mathematically more natural space of *anti-Hermitian* matrices as a Lie algebra (using the commutator). Of course, since simply multiplying by $i$ is a linear isomorphism from Hermitian matrices to anti-Hermitian matrices, one can induce the physicist' Lie algebra structure on the Hermitian matrices by declaring this to be a Lie algebra homomorphism. It's really just a matter of convention (though, sometimes, signs cause problems in the translation).

Comment: @RobertBryant:  Thanks for this --- but I'm not sure it answers the question.  In a math paper, is it less confusing to use $[A,B]$ for the commutator, or for the Lie bracket, or ought one not use this notation at all?

Comment: In a math paper, when the space is the *anti-Hermitian* matrices, we use the commutator $[,]$ and know that it is a Lie bracket.  Mostly (probably, there are some exceptions), mathematicians don't regard the *Hermitian* matrices as a Lie algebra, so there is no confusion.  In the rare cases when a mathematician wants to do something like this, he or she makes an explicit (re-)definition of the symbol and *warns the reader of the nonstandard usage*.  (Frequently, the referee objects anyway.)

Comment: @RobertBryant:  This sounds like it is probably the answer I'm looking for --- though, because there are two possible non-standard usages, I'd still like to know whether one is generally preferred to the other.

Comment: I can't help you there.  I never use either of these nonstandard conventions; they are equally bad from my point of view.

Comment: A compromise: $[iA,iB]=iC$, where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are Hermitian.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $[x,y]$ for a Lie bracket is fairly standard, although there are books on Lie algebras using $xy$ instead. Indeed, for matrices the notation $[A,B]$ may also denote the commutator $AB-BA$. This can be confusing if the subspace of matrices does form a Lie algebra, but not with respect to the standard commutator, e.g., for $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ with respect to the Hermitian Pauli matrices; or for other cases, where the Lie bracket is given more generally by
$$[A,B]:=AQB-BPA$$
for specific matrices $P$ and $Q$, not necessarily the identity matrix, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207459/earliest-source-for-a-lie-algebra-construction/207623#207623). 
Suppose we have a Lie algebra $L$ of matrices where $AB-BA$ does not define a Lie brakcet. Then we might pass to an isomorphic Lie algebra $L'$ in some $\mathfrak{g}l_n(K)$ by Ado's theorem, so that $AB-BA$ in $L'$ defines a Lie bracket (see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391106/meaning-of-a-b-when-a-and-b-are-self-adjoint/1391139#1391139)).

Comment: Actually, the paper you link to (in the answer you link to) denotes the non-standard Lie bracket $(A,B)$, not $[A,B]$.